# Autowire annotation working in Controller but not anywhere else?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-annotations

I am using Spring 4.1.1.
I have the following in my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.au.controller,com.au.util" /> 
<mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/**" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/caballocation" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="AddImplDao" class="com.au.dao.AddressDaoImpl" />
```

I have the following controller class in package com.au.controller

```
  @Controller
  public class ControllerMain {

    @Autowired
    AddressDao obj;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public @ResponseBody String test(){
        //logger.debug("getWelcome is executed!");
        obj.select();
        return "1";
    }

}
```

In the above code obj.select works as it gets autowired.

But the following class which is in com.au.util package have the value null of the object which is autowired.

```
    public class DistanceCalculator {

        @Autowired
        AddressDao obj1;
        public String calculate(String from, String to) throws IOException, JSONException {
        ..
        Map output = obj1.calc(from, to);
        ..
        }
```

**Obj1 is null while execution. Getting java.lang.NullPointerException at obj1.calc(from,to)**

Following is the interface and its implementation.
AddressDao.java

```
public interface AddressDao {
    public void select();
    public Map calc(String from,String to);
}
```

AddressDaoImpl.java

```
public class AddressDaoImpl implements AddressDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
       this.simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("CheckForValuesInDB");
    }

    @Override
    public void select() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public Map calc(String from, String to) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion Yes i got nullPointerException in DistanceCalculator class as mentioned above

Comment: Instead of this <context:component-scan base-package="com.au.controller,com.au.util" />  can you try THIS? <context:component-scan base-package="com.au" />. Also instead of doing this: <bean id="AddImplDao" class="com.au.dao.AddressDaoImpl" />, add @Service annotation on your AddressDaoImpl class.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion I tried this. Still the same error

Comment: @RossiRobinsion In distanceCalculator.java i am getting error but in MainController.java it is gettting autowired

Answer (score -1):

you have to add extra space in com.au.controller,com.au.util so it should look like 'com.au.controller, com.au.util'. As for now only com.au.controller is scanned by your configuration.

//Edit
There should be @Component annotation in DistanceCalculator class